# "Unable to execute" message in Rodeo with Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, rodeo

I'm a complete noob in Python, so please forgive this question if it's completely stupid. I had Canopy 1.4.7 installed on my system, working with Python 2.7. I just upgraded to Canopy 2.1.2, with Python 3.5.

I'd been using Rodeo 2.5.2 as my environment. It worked like a charm with 1.4.7, but since the upgrade, I haven't been able to get it to work. All I get is a message saying "Unable to execute." The Rodeo terminal then has to be restarted.

As a matter of fact, any code input doesn't work. I tried to put code into the Rodeo terminal; it doesn't even register the input. I can't press "Enter," nothing happens. I tried to install a package; nothing happened. I've tried reinstalling both Canopy and Rodeo, but to no effect. I've also tried turning it off and on again (thanks, Roy). Mind you, I tried the same codes in the Canopy environment, and they worked fine. So I'm assuming it's an issue in Rodeo.

Comment: I am facing the same problem however, on my laptop, my code is a very lengthy one, So if I trigger the code in parts, it works properly but selecting a large chunk (>300 lines) or something throws this error. Even I have not go a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error attempting to run a source file having more than 500 lines (code, comments and empty lines) in Rodeo 2.5.2. I am not sure what is the actual maximum (?) number of lines allowed (if any) but removing some comments and thus reducing the total number of lines to 514 allowed to run that file.